# Android get object id from ParseObject

Tags: android, parse-platform

I've a query for getting column value of datatype pointer from table parse. My problem is when I get values from object, the output/result is different/wrong.

For example in Callback I use `String id = parseObject.get("Subject").toString();` here datatype of `Subject` is pointer. For this my expected result is `1MEWbkTJpN` but the result is `com.parse.ParseUser@2b44e70`. How can I convert ParseObject to get the original object id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my own answer instead of using String we have to use ParseObject and then we get parseObject.getObjectId().